# Compound Continuous Interest

Tags: logarithms

Suppose that I have 100 dollars and this amount has increased up to 150 within 5 years, in order to get the growth rate we solve the following equation $\ln(150/100)×100/5= 0.081=8.1$%

The question is what if this amount has increased within seconds or minutes or days how do I calculate it then?!

I guess we must divide $5$ to convert it to minutes or seconds or days, is that right?!

Comment: This is compound continuous interest?

Comment: @Fleablood, Yes it is.

Comment: The number of years need not be an integer greater than $1$.  It could be a real number less than $1$.  But you should express it as years.  So if for $5$ minutes.  There are $60*24*365$ minutes in a year so $5 minute = \frac 5{60*24*365}$.  So instead of dividing by $5 years$  divide by $\frac {5}{60*24*365} years$.  (which is the same thing as multiplying by $\frac {60*24*365}5$.

Comment: @fleablood, please can you re-write this in an answer

Comment: I already did write it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the comment you said an example with the minutes please

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same way.  Let $a$ be the number of years.  $a$ can be any positive real number and it can be less than $1$.  So do $\ln \frac {\text{end ammount}}{\text{initial amount}}*\frac 1a \times 100\%$

So if $a = 57$ days $=\frac {57}{365}years$ then and the end amount is $\$102$ then the rate is $\frac{\ln \frac {102}{100}\times 100\%}{\frac {57}{365}} = 12.7\%$

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to write Fleablood's comment here+ thanks for him

The number of years need not be an integer greater than $1$.  It could be a real number less than $1$.  But you should express it as years.  So if for $5$ minutes.  There are $60*24*365$ minutes in a year so $5 minute = \frac 5{60*24*365}$.  So instead of dividing by $5 years$  divide by $\frac {5}{60*24*365} years$.  (which is the same thing as multiplying by $\frac {60*24*365}5$.